# 'Fruits' questions that need to be closed or deleted

Tags: discussion

Before the closing of this fine First of April, there are a few [fruits](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruits) questions that have been deemed sub-par and will likely result in closure or deletion (typically the former to allow people to retain their rep).

### The following questions will be closed or deleted:

---

<s>**#Question 1:** [List of anime with watermelon smashing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/list-of-anime-with-watermelon-smashing)</s>

<s>**Judgment:** Not constructive; too broad</s>

**Fate:** <s>Closure</s> Deleted

---

**#Question 2:** [Why did Yui got upset when Nodoka ate the strawberry off her cake?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3193/why-did-yui-got-upset-when-nodoka-ate-the-strawberry-off-her-cake)

**Judgment:** Not constructive; too localized

**Fate:** Deletion

---

**#Question 3:** [Does each Sohmas' appearance correlate to a fruit?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3194/does-each-sohmas-appearance-correlate-to-a-fruit)

**Judgment:** Not constructive; not much evidence to support this question

**Fate:** Closure

---

**#Question 4:** [From what anime is this character who is holding an apple?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3183/from-what-anime-is-this-character-who-is-holding-an-apple)

**Judgment:** Not constructive; silly and pointless

**Fate:** Closure, for the sake of @ShotgunNinja.

---

**#Question 5:** [Who is this character hugging an apple?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3172/who-is-this-character-hugging-an-apple)

**Judgment:** Not a real question; controversial

**Fate:** EXTERMINATION!

---

**#Question 6:** [Are the Sailor Moon colors based on types of fruit?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/are-the-sailor-moon-colors-based-on-types-of-fruit)

**Judgment:** Not constructive

**Fate:** Closure

---

**#Question 7:** [Are the Tuffles actually fruits?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/are-the-tuffles-actually-fruits)

**Judgment:** Not constructive

**Fate:** Closure

---

**#Question 8:** [Is Fruit Ninja actually based on Naruto?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/is-fruit-ninja-actually-based-on-naruto)

**Judgment:** Not constructive

**Fate:** Deletion

---

<s>**#Question 9:** [What anime are all of these fruits from?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/what-anime-are-all-of-these-fruits-from)</s>

<s>**Judgment:** Too localized</s>

**Fate:** <s>Closure</s> Repealed

---

### The following are borderline and can be saved from closure with some edits:

---

<s>**#Question 1:** [Why is Tangelo Island named as such?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3187/why-is-tangelo-island-named-as-such)</s>

<s>**Reason:** Inaccurate question; translation error: Tangelo Island is called "Bontan" Island in Japan.</s>

<s>**Suggestion:** Fix error.</s>

---

<s>**#Question 2:** [Why were the 765 idols dressed as fruits?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3152/why-were-the-765-idols-dressed-as-fruits)</s>

<s>**Reason:** Too many questions</s>

<s>**Suggestion:** Separate the part that goes "Third, later on in the episode, Jupiter is shown holding some fruits:" into another question.</s>

---

**Update** -- All of the mentioned question have been closed (excluding the borderline ones), some pending deletion.

I plan on removing the [fruits](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruits) tag from non-closed questions after all of this resolves.

If you think a question should be added to this list or that a judgment needs to be appealed, or even if you have a comment, suggestions or general objection, feel free to let me know.

**Update 2** -- [fruits](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruits) are no more.

Comment: I think I've fixed the iM@S one. If you think it's still too broad then tell me and I can shrink the scope even more.

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/what-anime-are-all-of-these-fruits-from <-- I think this is also quite localized...

Comment: @nhahtdh noted, closed, and added to the list.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree that one should be closed. I agree it's pretty random, but as an identification question I don't see what's too localized about it. Identifying an anime based on a screenshot is something we're allowing. I don't see how this is any more localized than other identification request questions based on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized. It's demonstrably within our community's ability to answer it and the answer was interesting enough to garner several upvotes (though that could also be due to [tag:fruit])

Comment: Sure, it's a pretty strange question, and it's fine if people downvote it for that reason, but I think closing it sets a bad precedent against some types of identification questions which in my view should still be allowed. If I wanted to identify an anime, but all I had was background art, would that be allowed? Or what if I wanted to [identify an anime based on a minor side-story](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2379/title-of-an-anime-with-this-certain-side-story)? Anyway it's not so important since that question isn't likely to have any more activity, but IMO it should be open.

Comment: @LoganM Alright, I'll repeal the argument in light of your objections.

Comment: @LoganM: I think the identification request should show something that is not too generic. In the case of that question, we only see a bunch of fruits, which I think is not a reasonable amount of information for the answerer to work on.

Comment: @nhahtdh It seems a bit strange to me that you're claiming there is not a reasonable amount of information to work on when the question was answered within an hour of being posted. Also, I don't think displaying a lot of different fruits together in an anime is actually very generic. I can't think of any other anime with similar scenes. I will admit it's a pretty minor detail about the show, but I'm not sure why that's a problem.

Comment: @LoganM: `it's a pretty minor detail about the show, but I'm not sure why that's a problem.` The fact that it is not characteristic of the actual show makes it looks more of [challenge to find out how *into* the show one is]. Maybe I'd tolerate one or two such question, but I wouldn't want to see a bunch of identification with such minor clue provided.

Comment: @nhahtdh I can agree with that. It would be a bit of a problem if we got lots of questions like this. However, there haven't been many such questions, and unless we reach a point that they actually become a problem I think it's better not to make any rules regarding this. For now, I think comments and (in some cases) downvotes are sufficient if you aren't satisfied with the level of detail provided in the post.

Comment: Love "Closure, for the sake of @ShotgunNinja".

Answer (score 2):

Of the seven posts listed as going to be "closed or deleted", I'm in favor of eventually deleting all of them as they are right now. The reputation will only affect a couple of people significantly, and there's  no helping that. Those people could probably gain that reputation back in a few days, and if they can't we should be questioning whether they really deserve it in the first place. More importantly, if we kept those questions closed but not deleted, and they stay highly upvoted, it would send a strange signal to new users as to what's acceptable and what the standards of this community are.

Closed questions aren't intended to stay in that state forever. They're supposed to either get deleted or get modified and reopened. None of those seem to be easily modifiable to be valid questions. If the OPs think they can make them into serious constructive and on-topic questions, then they can request some time to do so. However, closure shouldn't be our long-term strategy for dealing with garbage.

Of course, they have some historical relevance, but I don't think they qualify for a historical lock. A historical lock is supposed to indicate high-quality content that isn't technically allowed, but these are low quality posts. In my opinion the best thing to do is to make a meta post with links to all of the [fruits](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruits) questions, both deleted and still alive. That way established users can still find them, but they don't send a bad message to new users.

Comment: Or wait 60 days before deleting them. Deleted posts with +3 and deleted after 60 days keep their rep.

Comment: @Mysticial I don't think we should be that concerned with the rep. I'm more concerned with people stumbling upon our site in the next few days and seeing a ton of closed questions.